# Why is Belle the only Disney Princess who hasn’t been made Queen in the remakes?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

All the Disney Princesses that got their films remade have been made queen: Cinderella, Aurora, Jasmine (Sultan). But why hasn't Belle been made queen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belle was never a queen in the original films, was a peasant and as far as we know, never married Beast, and would unlikely be accepted as the queen of France, as Beast was not the King of France, but simply the prince.

The Queen was very much alive still in the movie. Until she perishes, and Beast and Belle marry, she will not become Queen.

Comment: But the Queen died in the Days in the Sun flashback and Belle and the Beast are in love, so why WOULDN’T they marry?

Comment: Marriage is not mandatory when in love! Its also not important to the story, it can simply be implied.